# AttributeError 'unicode' object has no attribute 'numero'

Tags: python, django, forms, unicode

I'm new with django, so I apologize for this (probably) dumb question:

I'm trying to make a form based on the content of a model named `Linea`that, depending of the input, redirects the user to a view named `lineas_detalles`. If the input is not a part of the model `Linea`the form is supposed to do nothing.

I can perfectly load the page where the form is, but when I enter something and I submit I get the error:

```
AttributeError at /lineas/
'unicode' object has no attribute 'numero'
```

The content that is intended to go into the form is a number.

**lineas.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
[...]
{% block content %}
    <h1>Escoja una línea</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Actualizar</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Linea


class LineaForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Linea
        fields = ('linea',)
```

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class Linea(models.Model):
    linea = models.CharField(max_length=2)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.linea

[...]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    [...]
    url(r'^lineas/$', views.lineas, name='lineas'),
    url(r'^lineas/(?P<linea_numero>)/$', views.lineas_detalles, name='lineas_detalles'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import LineaForm


def lineas(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LineaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            linea = form.cleaned_data['linea']
            linea_numero = str(linea.numero)
            return redirect('lineas_detalles', linea_numero=linea_numero)
    else:
        form = LineaForm()
    return render(request, 'bustopapp/lineas.html', {'form': form})


def lineas_detalles(request):
    return render(request, 'bustopapp/lineas_detalles.html', {})


[...]
```

The traceback marcks the origin of the problem in this line of the `views.py` file: `linea_numero = str(linea.numero)`

---

**Update 1**

Following the correction of *Jaime Sanz* the AttributeError is corrected. Now the code look like this:

**forms.py**

```
[...]
class LineaForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Linea
        fields = ('numero',)
```

**models.py**

```
[...]
class Linea(models.Model):
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=2)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.numero
```

**views.py**

```
[...]
form = LineaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            linea = form.save(commit=False)
            linea_numero = str(linea.numero)
            return redirect('lineas_detalles', linea_numero=linea_numero)
[...]
```

The rest is the same as before. Anyway, now I get this other error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /lineas/
Reverse for 'lineas_detalles' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'linea_numero': '3'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['lineas/(?P<linea_numero>)/$']
```

With the traceback marking at tis line in views.py:

```
return redirect('lineas_detalles', linea_numero=linea_numero)
```

I'm learning programming by myself, sorry if these questions are too basic.

---

**Update 2**

I've made some changes, so now I don't have any error:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^lineas/(?P<linea_numero>\d+)/$', views.lineas_detalles, name='lineas_detalles'),
```

**views.py**

```
def lineas_detalles(request, linea_numero):
    return render(request, 'bustopapp/lineas_detalles.html', {})
```

But now I realize that regardless of what number I type in the form, the `Lineas` view sends me to the `Lineas_detalles` view. Initially my intention was to show an error when something that is not in the database is typed in the form.

Comment: The error already speaks for itself, `linea` is a unicode object(just consider it as a string), unicode object doesn't have an attribute `numero`, what else you are not clear about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, indeed, in your views.py. This line:

```
linea = form.cleaned_data['linea']
```

doesn't return an instance of the model Linea, it returns the value that the 'linea' *field* has in your form. To get the Linea instance you have to save the form:

```
form = LineaForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    linea = form.save()
    linea_numero = str(linea.numero)
```

This will, however, save the changes to the database. If you don't want that, you can do the same, but with:

```
linea = form.save(commit=False)
```

**edit** also, your Linea model doesn't seem to have a 'numero' attribute

Comment: Gracias Jaime :)  Anyway, If you could read the update I would be grateful.